# Alexa Skill: Invocation name: How to catch the skill STARTING PHRASE?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on my coming soon music player skill.
I'd like to have different behaviour following a different skil linvocation, by example:

**1. start immediately the audio streaming:**

```
Play MyMusicSkillName
```

**2. just introduce the skill behaviour with a welcome/help message:**

```
Open MyMusicSkillName
```

My question is:
There is a way to distinguish the invocation VERB, getting the invocation starting phrase (and distinguish in LaunchRequest event)?
Any idea?

---

See documentation: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/understanding-how-users-invoke-custom-skills.html#invoking-a-skill-with-no-specific-request-no-intent

> Ask  Alexa, Ask Daily Horoscopes
>
> Begin  Alexa, Begin Trivia Master
>
> Launch  Alexa, Launch Car Fu
>
> Load  Alexa, Load Daily Horoscopes
>
> Open  Alexa, Open Daily Horoscopes
>
> Play  Alexa, Play Trivia Master
>
> Play the game  Alexa, Play the game Trivia Master
>
> Resume  Alexa, Resume Trivia Master
>
> Run  Alexa, Run Daily Horoscopes
>
> Start  Alexa, Start Daily Horoscopes
>
> Start playing the game  Alexa, Start playing the game
>   Trivia Master
>
> Tell  Alexa, Tell Daily Horoscopes
>
> Use  Alexa, Use Daily Horoscopes

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the `LaunchRequest` does not provide any way to differentiate how the user opened your skill.

However, you can differentiate between a new user and a user who has used the skill before by saving something in your database such as a `last_played` audio. Then when you handle the `LaunchRequest`, you can check that user's ID in your database and if they have a `last_played` entry, then automatically continue playing. Or if its a new user, then provide an introduction/welcome message.

Returning users who you think want to hear the introduction message by saying "Open" instead of "Play" probably want to be reminded of what to do or what options the skill has, which you should handle in the `HelpIntent` anyway. So if your skill auto played for them, they should naturally ask a question of your skill that will launch the `HelpIntent`.

Comment: Upvoted. I appreciated your suggestions.
`HelpIntent` management is more a workaround, but ok.
BTW. the lack of the invocation phrase as a request parameter s a "bug". Don't you think?

Comment: It's a lacking feature for sure. I work with both Alexa and Lex and it's amazing how different they are. The biggest surprise to me was that every Lex interaction provides exactly what the user input as a value inside the request JSON. Having it is incredibly useful. Why Alexa does not is a mystery to me.

Comment: Yes.Surprisingly, as far as I understand, in Alexa's user utterances in input are not passed through the skill for a free processing; instead user input is able to just 'fire' predetermined fixed intents. That's too limiting and could be just an option, beside the option to process the user utterance with a skill NLP.